# Another API call inside ng-repeat by passing first API Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring-boot

I have an angular application which I need to call web services. I have to call two different URL to get data. In my first URL is like
 **==> abc.com/student/3** this is the list of student. and another URL is **abc.com/parent/idofStudent3** when I pass student id of 3 in the second URL I need to get parent first name from the second URL.

I am able to retrieve the first URL data but I am unable to retrieve second URL data by passing first record data in ng-repeat. Could you please help me how to retrieve parent name in the web page?

Html Page

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in myWelcome">
{{x.firstname}} || {{x.parentId}} </h1>
```

Here instead of displaying parentid I need to call another web service to display parent name by passing parentId as a parameter. how to call another web service here?

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("abc.com/student/3")
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
            });
    });
</script>
```

==> First webservice response is like :

```
 {
    "student":[
    {
         "name":"john",
         "parentId": 12,
         "address":"NYC"
    },
    {
         "name":"Rohi",
         "parentId": 14,
         "address":"NJ"
    },
 ]
}
```

==> second webservice response is like this when parentId=12:

```
{
   "firstName": "Sr. John",
}
======> when parentId 14

{
    "firstName": "Sr. Rohi",
}


-------------------------
firstname || parentName
-------------------------
John      ||  Sr. John
Rohi      ||   Sr. Rohi
```

Answer (score 2):

I strongly discourage the use of controller function inside angular `ng-repeat` because it is called several times during the digest cycle. The best way for you in this case would be to use of the angular directives. You can put your HTML as

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in myWelcome">
{{x.firstname}} || 
 <get-parent-name child='x' parent-name='parentName[$index]'>{{parentName[$index]}}</get-parent-name>
</h1>
```

In your controller declare the parentName as `$scope.parentName = {}`

And inside the js file add a new directive `getParentName` like this

```
module.directive('getParentName', function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope : {
           child : '=',
           parentName : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            var childId = scope.child.id;
            $http.get("abc.com/parent/" + childId)
                .then(function(response) {
                    scope.parentName = response.data.parentName;
                });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try by doing below changes.

```
<h1 ng-repeat="x in myWelcome">
{{x.firstname}} || {{ getparentname(x.parentId) }} </h1>
```

and write function in your controller. like below

```
 $scope.getparentname = function(data){
    //write you api here
 }
```